# Using wcf how to upload a image

Tags: wcf

using wcf/wcf web services to upload a images give me with example?

In my project i want to upload image by using WCF

Answer (score 2):

Basically you should use [WCF streaming](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP).

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITransferService
{ 
    [OperationContract]
     void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request); 
}

public void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
{
    FileStream targetStream = null;
    Stream sourceStream =  request.FileByteStream;

    string uploadFolder = @"C:\\upload\\";

    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, request.FileName);

    using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, 
                          FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        //read from the input stream in 65000 byte chunks

        const int bufferLen = 65000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
        {
            // save to output stream
            targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        targetStream.Close();
        sourceStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert the image to a byte array before sending it, and then converting it back to an image on the destination site.

Here are two methods for doing just that:

```
public byte[] ImageToByteArray( Image image)
{
  var ms = new MemoryStream();
  image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
  return ms.ToArray();
}

public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArray)
{
  var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
  return Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

That means your web service can have a method something like this:

```
public void UploadImage( byte[] imageData )
{
  var image = ByteArrayToImage( imageData );
  //save image to disk here, or do whatever you like with it
}
```